# Media Queries Are Not Overriding Each Other

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a problem with my media queries as it is not overriding each other. The first iteration `(max-width: 960px)` works fine but the second one `(max-width: 380px)` does not work and I do not know why. Help is appreciated, thanks.

```css
.fb {
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {

/* this works */

.fb {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px!important;
    margin-left: 15px!important;
    margin-right: 15px!important;                
             }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {

/* this does not work */
.fb {

    width: 30px!important;
    margin-left: 10px!important;
    margin-right: 10px!important;               
             }
}
```

```html
<div class="social_container">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img class="fb" src= "http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why `!important`? Also, you have a typo in your last rule: `margin-rigth`. What exactly "does not work"?

Comment: Can you please post a valid small code snippet with a example image? We can't debug what we can't see.

Comment: Sure, just a second.

Comment: Use an example image from e.g. placekitten.com.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: The image does not turn smaller. If I don't put the ' !important ' even the first media query won't work.

Comment: It works. I only copy/pasted your code: http://codepen.io/connexo/pen/woryXy and removed the `!important`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are wrongly spelled **margin-rigth** please change it to **margin-right** and remove **!important**

```css
.fb {
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .fb {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  .fb {
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="social_container">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <img class="fb" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzPkq.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Now also press "Tidy" button in code editor, and I will upvote. Also I recommend you use image placeholder service like placehold.it or placekitten.com.

Comment: Apart from the typo, the snippet does work so it must be an error in my HTML. I'll accept this answer and try to find the problem from the rest of my code. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/87kt4qyp/)

```css
.social_container a {
    color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {


.social_container a{
    color: green;
}

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {

.social_container a{

    color: pink;
             }
}
```

```html
<div class="social_container">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">fb</a>
</div>
```

Comment: OP's selector is totally valid and not a problem here. How is your answer any useful at all?